# JSP/Javascript: How to dynamically change a header based on the page im on

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a header.jsp file that is included in all my pages on the website what acts as a template for all my header content (e.g site titles, logos, home links etc.). Inside this header.jsp I want to set up a page title in a h1 tag (for example) that would change to show the title of whatever page I am on when navigating through the pages of the website.

My initial thought was to use javascript to achieve this however based on the tutorials, most people are using frameworks like angular which I dont really want to resort to using unless there was no alternative. Is there any way I can change my headers to pick up whatever page I am on using raw JavaScript? Or, is there anything in jsp that can also make this possible? If so how can I achieve this?

Comment: In theory, if you set up your page correctly, you could do this using pure javascript, yes.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the page title as a request attribute `page_title` and then fetching it in your `header.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. I have managed to figure out one alternative that has worked for me though I wouldnt say it is the most graceful. (Any suggestions to improve this and I will update my answer for better understanding!) Also worth noting the solution was using jsp NOT javascript.

What I have done is within my header.jsp, I had set up in the body the following code between a div tag:

```
<%= subTitle %>
```

From there, I then applied the following code to all other pages on my website:

```
<% String subTitle="Example Page"; %>
```

'Example page' being the name of the webpage that I want to show on my header but it can be different on any page and had given me the expected results.

The only thing is however that in doing it this way, when it is set on Eclipse Luna I get a problem where 'subTitle cannot be resolved to a variable'. The code in itself works but it is problems like these that I would also rather resolve in order to provide the best solution. Any suggestions to remove this error would be appreciated.